# Shut down migrations from EE?

Tags: discussion, migration

The moderators at EE seem to use DIY as a dumping ground for anything that is off-topic there that is even vaguely building-wiring adjacent, for example [questions about designing an industrial three-phase-powered glass furnace](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/292613/wiring-a-temporary-disconnect-with-signals-when-close-or-open) that obviously have nothing to do with Home Improvement.

I think we should shut down this migration avenue so they can’t abuse it any more, if that’s possible.

Comment: While I agree that particular question was not a good fit for DIY, there are others that are good fits. And there are times it would be nice to easily move a DIY post **to** EE. But the tools for doing this are very limited. Ideal would be something like an option on "Close" - actually I think there is something like that but it only allows for Meta -> main and vice versa.

Comment: Considering we have absolutely _ZERO_ "other site" migration targets, it does feel like we're a dumping ground. Unfortunately, we've had circuit design questions here that would be ideal to migrate to [electronic.se], but that requires a "Moderator Attention" flag which just seems more difficult (from a user perspective) even if both paths take effort from a mod.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately migrations can't be blocked from the target site's side. The only tool at our disposal is to close the question as off-topic, which bumps it back to the originating site but leaves it closed.

I've let the moderator involved with this migration know that it's off-topic here, and asked them to post in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement) if they have questions about our scope.